# Riak 2 partitions waiting to handoff indefinitely

Tags: riak

I'm running a 16 nodes cluster (`Riak 2.1.7`)
I have 2 partitions which are stuck in the "waiting to handoff" state for a long time.
The 2 partitions in question types are secondary instead of being primary

```
riak-admin cluster partitions
```

All nodes seem to be up, but I'm still having the following errors

```
[error] <0.13307.2430>@riak_core_handoff_sender:start_fold:282 hinted transfer of riak_kv_vnode from 'riak@g37.xxx.com' 954828706420287160427993313561712246240057491456 to 'riak@g39.xxx.com' 954828706420287160427993313561712246240057491456 failed because of error:{badmatch,{error,closed}} [{riak_core_handoff_sender,start_fold,5,[{file,"src/riak_core_handoff_sender.erl"},{line,132}]}]
```

Any help please?

I've tried to repair the partition and restart the Node.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happened before the partitions needed handoff? Do you have nodes leaving or joining the ring?

You might want to double check your Riak KV version as 2.1.7 does not exist. However, 2.0.7 and 2.9.7 do. If you execute `riak version` from the command line, it should tell you.

It sounds like you have a stuck set of transfers. The usual fix for this is to stop all transfers with `riak-admin transfer-limit 0`, wait for a few minutes and then set the transfer limit back to whatever it was before e.g. to return to the default setting of 2, use `riak-admin transfer-limit 2`.

Assuming you have an n-val of 3 or higher (default setting is 3), you could potentially delete the content of the partitions on one node from disk and then repair them. That should clear anything that should be blocking them. As you say they are not primary partitions, there should be no risk of data loss.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. riak-admin status | grep riak_kv_version command shows riak_kv_version : <<"2.1.7-226">>. riak version output is empty. I will try to stop all transfers as you suggested. Currently my transfer-limit is set to 4. is it too high?

Comment: The Riak Version you are pulling is that of the Riak KV component within Riak which may or may not change between releases of Riak. As mentioned, `riak version` will output the actual release version of Riak you are using.
Regarding the transfer limit, there is no one size fits all for this. If your cluster has spare resource capacity, this will be fine as is, especially if you are using the more aggressive claimv3 algorithm. If your cluster is low on spare resources, drop it to 2 or even 1. Note that you can specify per node as well e.g. `riak-admin transfer-limit <nodename> <value>`